# Java "for" statement iteration based on a string

Tags: java

here's my question. how do I put a string in a for statement
example: for (the string being entered by user.equals(X))
                    do this
i want this method so the statement repeats itself until that desired specific string is entered by the user

Comment: have you tried `while (!user.equals(X) ) { .... }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shoudl totally do what you want. If user enters a name that is not equal to "Mike" then the loop will continue. Hope it helps!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String name = "Mike";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    String user = scan.nextLine();

    while (!user.equals(name)) { 
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        user = scan.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Good bye");

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a `key` for the exit of a while loop [**q in this example**], and read the user input until the condition is met.

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to ....");
        System.out.println("press \"q\" to exit or just type word until the end of the life");
        String userInput =scan.nextLine();
        while (!"q".equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)) {
            System.out.println("The user input was: " + userInput);
            System.out.println("try again please (\"q\" to exit) ");
            userInput =scan.nextLine();
        }

    } // Ends playGame
```

so this code will ask the user to give an string until q in passed...

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
for( ; !user.equals(X) ;)
  { user = <scanner input> ;  //accept a scanner input  }
```

shall help you.